RCD testing using a plugin tester in an outlet without ground
I have a plugin tester which tests different electrical faults such as open ground, swaps etc. There is also an RCD test button. I put this in an outlet where there is no ground, only neutral and live and I didn't see the RCCB trip in my breaker box. In an outlet where there is a ground the RCCB trips fine.
From what I understand the plugin tester puts a small current to the ground to create an imbalance which trips the RCCB. Since there is no ground in the outlet, the RCCB does not trip is my understanding. Is my understanding correct?

Yes, your understanding is correct.
